# Extract values from deepdiff output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-diff

I have compared two json file with deepdiff lib. But can figure Out the output.
My output -

> {**'values_changed'**: {'root': {'new_value': '{\n "quiz": {\n "sport": {\n "q1": {\n "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",\n "options": [\n "New York Bulls",\n "Los Angeles Kings",\n "Golden Staxx000xxxte Warriros",\n "Huston Rocket"\n ],\n "answer": "Huston Rocket"\n }\n },\n "maths": {\n "q1": {\n "questxxx000xxcion": "5 + 7 = ?",\n "options": [\n "10",\n "11",\n "12",\n "13"\n ],\n "answer": "12"\n },\n "qx0000xx2": {\n "question": "12 - 8 = ?",\n "options": [\n "1",\n "2",\n "3",\n "4"\n ],\n "answer": "4"\n }\n }\n }\n}', **'old_value'**: '{\n "quiz": {\n "sport": {\n "q1": {\n "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",\n "options": [\n "New York Bulls",\n "Los Angeles Kings",\n "Golden Staxxxxxte Warriros",\n "Huston Rocket"\n ],\n "answer": "Huston Rocket"\n }\n },\n "maths": {\n "q1": {\n "questxxxxxcion": "5 + 7 = ?",\n "options": [\n "10",\n "11",\n "12",\n "13"\n ],\n "answer": "12"\n },\n "qxxx2": {\n "question": "12 - 8 = ?",\n "options": [\n "1",\n "2",\n "3",\n "4"\n ],\n "answer": "4"\n }\n }\n }\n}', **'diff'**: '--- \n+++ \n@@ -6,7 +6,7 @@\n "options": [\n "New York Bulls",\n "Los Angeles Kings",\n- "Golden Staxxxxxte Warriros",\n+ "Golden Staxx000xxxte Warriros",\n "Huston Rocket"\n ],\n "answer": "Huston Rocket"\n@@ -14,7 +14,7 @@\n },\n "maths": {\n "q1": {\n- "questxxxxxcion": "5 + 7 = ?",\n+ "questxxx000xxcion": "5 + 7 = ?",\n "options": [\n "10",\n "11",\n@@ -23,7 +23,7 @@\n ],\n "answer": "12"\n },\n- "qxxx2": {\n+ "qx0000xx2": {\n "question": "12 - 8 = ?",\n "options": [\n "1",'}}}

And the output I Want-

```
values_changed : 
{
    "quiz": {
        "sport": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                "options": [
                    "New York Bulls",
                    "Los Angeles Kings",
                    "Golden Staxxxxxte Warriros",
                    "Huston Rocket"
                ],
                "answer": "Huston Rocket"
            }
        },
        "maths": {
            "q1": {
                "questxxxxxcion": "5 + 7 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "10",
                    "11",
                    "12",
                    "13"
                ],
                "answer": "12"
            },
            "qxxx2": {
                "question": "12 - 8 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
                    "4"
                ],
                "answer": "4"
            }
        }
    }
}

old_value _ 
{
    "quiz": {
        "sport": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                "options": [
                    "New York Bulls",
                    "Los Angeles Kings",
                    "Golden Staxx000xxxte Warriros",
                    "Huston Rocket"
                ],
                "answer": "Huston Rocket"
            }
        },
        "maths": {
            "q1": {
                "questxxx000xxcion": "5 + 7 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "10",
                    "11",
                    "12",
                    "13"
                ],
                "answer": "12"
            },
            "qx0000xx2": {
                "question": "12 - 8 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
                    "4"
                ],
                "answer": "4"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```py
import json
from deepdiff import DeepDiff

# assuming t1 and t2 are two json data
ddiff = DeepDiff(t1, t2)
jsoned = ddiff.to_json()

print(json.dumps(jsoned, indent=4))
```